# How to invoke script that uses scan() on Windows?

Tags: windows, r, rscript

How to invoke an R script like the following

```
scan()
```

in Windows? When using either `R` or `Rscript`, nothing is read. With `Rscript` or `littler` (both on Linux) the script works as expected.

```
# Doesn't work because stdin is already redirected
R --no-save < test.R

# Works on Linux, doesn't on Windows
Rscript test.R

# Works on Linux, doesn't exist in Windows
r test.R
```

Is there any way at all to achieve this without changing the R code?

Perhaps related: Why is there no `--interactive` switch in Windows?

Comment: Please present us with a reproducible example.

Comment: This is discussed in an [R devel post](http://r.789695.n4.nabble.com/Wait-for-user-input-with-readline-td3054517.html).

Comment: Never tried on Windows (so I don't post it as an answer) but a script containing `scan(file("stdin"))` will work on a Mac.

Comment: @plannapus It does work on Windows. I'll let you post the answer if you want to get the points. You have to modify it slightly so that it takes `character` and you have to hit `Ctrl+Z` to end scanning: `input<-scan(file("stdin"), what = character())
`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So as we discussed in the comments and with confirmation of @nograpes, you can use the following:

```
scan(file("stdin"), what=character())
```

in a script instead of `scan()` to read interactively from standard input when the script is executed in the command-line interface.
You then need to hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Z</kbd> to end scanning under Windows (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>D</kbd> on a Mac).

Comment: Why is the behavior different in Windows and Unix?

Comment: I'm working on a Mac (so Unix) and I have to supply `file("stdin")` as well. I have no competence in Linux, so can't really help on that one I guess.